# appname.herokuapp.com is redirecting me to www.appname.com after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ovh

I got a project which is deployed before in evolix server with the domain name `www.appname.com` ( OVH domain ).

I migrate the project to heroku. After deployment when i click on the link `appname.herokuapp.com` it's redirected me to www.appname.com which is down as our project is no longer in evolix.

can someone explain me this issue ? and what should I do to fix it ?

I spent so much time looking for a solution but i didn't find something useful is this situation.

Comment: Have you read the instruction how to configure custom domains for heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains?

Comment: The only two things you should have to do to make things work is adding a CNAME entry on your DNS configuration on OVH side (subdomain www aiming at appname.herokuapp.com) and setting www.appname.com as an accepted domain on your app dashboard. You also may have to reset your DNS configuration to avoid useless entries following your migration on Heroku.